# How to check whether a column contains only identical elements in R?

Tags: r

Example data:

```
x <- matrix(c("Stack","Stack","Stack",
              "Overflow","Overflow","wolfrevO"),
            nrow=3,ncol=2)
```

How can I check whether `x[,1]` contains entirely identical elements?

If `x` contains `NA`s, does this method still apply?

Thanks

Comment: Maybe `apply(x,2,function(p) length(unique(p))==1)`, will return FALSE if there is one NA and 2 identical elements, but TRUE if there are 3 NAs (this checks for all columns, for just x[,1], you can do `length(unique(x[,1]))==1` or `length(unique(x[!is.na(x[,1]),1]))==1` to remove NAs before testing)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You count the unique elements of the column:

```
length(unique(x[,1]))==1
```

works even if there are NA's in your data.

For checking every column use:

```
apply(x, 2, function(a) length(unique(a))==1)
```

Comment: the 2nd one for checking every column is terrific.

Comment: if there's only one unique value in the vector, you actually can just do `unique(x)==1`, if that unique value is 1.

Comment: For me, `length(unique(x[,1]))==1` gives `TRUE` no matter how many unique elements are in the column, because length gives the number of columns (1). I need to use `count(unique(x[,1]))==1`

Answer (score 4):

You can compare the vector's first value to the rest of the vector.

```
all(x[-1, 1] == x[1, 1])
# [1] TRUE
```

If `NA` values are present, then this exact method does not still apply.  However, it can be easily rectified by using `na.omit()`.  For example -

```
## create a vector with an NA value
x2 <- c(x[, 1], NA)

## standard check returns NA
all(x2 == x2[1])
# [1] NA

## call na.omit() to remove, then compare
all(na.omit(x2) == x2[1])
# [1] TRUE
```

So then, with your matrix `x`, this last line would become

```
all(na.omit(x[-1, 1]) == x[1, 1])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `duplicated` function for this:

if `sum(!duplicated(x[,1]))==1` returns `TRUE` the column contains all identical values.

```
sum(!duplicated(x[,1]))==1
[1] TRUE

sum(!duplicated(x[,2]))==1
[1] FALSE
```

If `x` contains NAs this method will work, in the sense that all `NA` columns will return `TRUE` and mixed columns will return `FALSE`.

```
x <- matrix(c(NA,NA,NA,"Overflow","Overflow",NA),nrow=3,ncol=2)

sum(!duplicated(x[,2]))==1
[1] FALSE

sum(!duplicated(x[,1]))==1
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 3):

#### A comparison of the proposed methods:

```
x <- rep(1, 1000)
x[5] <- 0

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  all(duplicated(x)), 
  length(unique(x)) == 1, 
  dim(table(x)) == 1, 
  all(x == x[1]),
  times = 1000)

Unit: microseconds
                   expr      min       lq        mean   median       uq      max neval cld
     all(duplicated(x))   19.594   21.461   24.688356   22.861   24.727   74.646  1000  b 
 length(unique(x)) == 1   21.461   23.793   26.972993   25.193   26.127  156.755  1000  b 
     dim(table(x)) == 1 1067.422 1090.282 1144.309131 1123.872 1154.197 2072.795  1000   c
         all(x == x[1])    3.267    4.199    4.629929    4.200    4.666   22.394  1000 a
```

`x` is a column or a row. `Matrix`, `data.frame` or similar per row or column equality testing can be done with:

```
all(apply(X, 1, function(x){all(x == x[1])}))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see which elements are duplicated and how many times you can use `table`.

```
table(x[,1])
# Stack 
# 3 

table(x[,2])
# Overflow wolfrevO 
#    2        1
```

To see if there's only one unique value in a column, use `dim`.

```
dim(table(x[,1])) == 1
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: not working: x[2,1] = NA; dim(table(x[,1])) == 1 is still TRUE.

Comment: See `?table` for the `useNA` argument depending on how you want to handle `NA`. E.g., `dim(table(x[,1], useNA = "ifany"))`.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Richard Scriven for characters, factors, etc (`all(x[-1, 1] == x[1, 1])`).

For comparing numeric values, however, a more robust approach can be useful:

```
all.same <- function (x) {
    abs(max(x) - min(x)) < 8.881784e-16
    # the constant above is just .Machine$double.eps*4
}
apply(x, 2, all.same)
```